# React/Redux - Manage state of table with multiple columns of checkboxes

Tags: reactjs, redux

[Example Table multiple columns of checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hL0ir.png)

Imagine that I have a table with multiple columns.  Some columns are made up entirely of checkboxes.  How would you manage the state for that table?

When I click a checkbox, I imagine that I would want to dispatch an action to update the redux state with some unique identifier for that column, and then the index of the row.  For instance:

`column1: [0,1,5,10]
column2: [2,3,6]`

If I click column2, row 1, column2 would update to:

`column2: [0,2,3,6]`

Where column# is the key for that column, and each number in the array is the row.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow! do you have a specific question? this is kind of vague.

Comment: And it's not related to react or redux... it's just a question of how to organize data

Answer (score 1):

Rows are usually used to represent instances of objects. You have turned this on it's head by using columns to represent your instances. Even if your table is static, I would not try to represent the columns, but instead represent the row:

```
var data = [
  [false, false, false, true],
  [false, false, true, true]
];
```

This translates much more cleanly for use with React:

```
{data.map(row => {
  return (
    <tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" checked="{row[0] ? 'checked' : ''}"/></td>
     <td><input type="checkbox" checked="{row[1] ? 'checked' : ''}"/></td>
     <td><input type="checkbox" checked="{row[2] ? 'checked' : ''}"/></td>
     <td><input type="checkbox" checked="{row[3] ? 'checked' : ''}"/></td>
   </tr>);
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can organize your data also as an object:

`let data = [
  {
    columnOne: true,
    columnTwo: false,
    columnThree: true,
    columnHundred: 42
  },
  {
    columnOne: true,
    columnTwo: false,
    columnThree: true,
    columnHundred: 0
  },
  {
    columnOne: false,
    columnTwo: false,
    columnThree: true,
    columnHundred: 42
  },
]`

And then you can update `data` array